# Xcode 6 swift sample app memory usage

Tags: xcode, swift

I'm just starting to learn swift for the first time and I was running the sample spritekit project that comes with xcode 6 when you start a new game, the hello world app with a little spaceship spinning when you tap. When the app is executed in the ios simulator I can see the memory usage on xcode. The memory was about 56MB just for the hello world app. Is there any reason is using so much memory? or is this a normal amount of memory for such apps?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I assume you are running it in the simulator, which will have different memory usage characteristics than running it on an actual device.  You'll also have slightly different memory usage when running it in debug vs running it in release mode.  In other words, I wouldn't pay too much attention to the memory usage when running debug in a simulator.

Comment: I verified.  Actual memory usage on an iPhone 6 plus for the sample project comes in at around 10MB and jumps to about 12MB when you add a spacecraft to the scene.

Comment: Oh wow thanks! This explains a lot. It didn't make any sense to me as why it was using so much memory. Thanks Jeremy.

Comment: @elpita: If this is the answer to your question, show your appreciation by marking the check mark to accept it.